# What Technologies do Web Browsers use to Render on Windows?

Tags: html

e.g. firefox and chrome, under windows, do they use GDI (graphics device interface) to draw a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Limitations) and [newer technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Successor%3a_DirectWrite).